# Usb formatting Error in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, disk-formatting

[i cant fix this please help me.i use.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaS0E.png)

me use ubuntu and when formatting error and read only.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

- After selecting the SD card or USB, instead of clicking the gear icon to format,
  click the partition in the "Volumes" section.
- Delete the partition ("minus" icon)
- Create a new partition